# Mesh face selection by color range

Tags: shaders, selection-tools, glass, vertex-colors

I'm doing a scene inside a cathedral, starting from a scan. To make it short, I'm selecting the windows by hand and assigning a glass shader so the light can pass through.

[image]

It works, but, I was wondering if there is a way to automatically select the windows by using a color range.

Do you also suggest a different way to approach this project?

Many thanks!

Comment: Can u provide blend file?

Comment: Sure! https://ufile.io/fsbsk7kl